# Debugging a simple function

Tags: c++, debugging

So our professor gave us the task to debug this code. We can use the compiler and also try to use the gdb debugger.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> reversed(const std::vector<int>& v) {
  std::vector<int> result;
  for (std::size_t i = v.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) result.push_back(v[i]);
  return result;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (argc < 1) {
    std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " [number] [number]..." << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }
  std::cerr << "Reading in " << (argc - 1) << " numbers from stdin"
            << std::endl;
  std::vector<int> numbers;
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
    // atoi converts a string to a number
    int number = std::stoi(argv[i]);
    numbers.push_back(number);
  }

  std::cerr << "Reversing order of numbers" << std::endl;
  auto reverse = reversed(numbers);

  for (auto n : reverse) std::cout << n << std::endl;
}
```

When I use `g++ -Wall debug-1.cc` I get this:

```
debug-1.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
debug-1.cc:19:29: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘std::size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} and ‘int’ [-Wsign-compare]
   19 |   for (std::size_t i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
```

I also used the Debugger a put a breakpoint to lines 19, 20 and 21:

```
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=32767, argv=0x7ffff7fafee0 <std::wcerr>)
    at debug-1.cc:11
11  int main(int argc, char** argv) {
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Reading in 0 numbers from stdin

Breakpoint 2, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf08) at debug-1.cc:19
19    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 3, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf08) at debug-1.cc:21
21      int number = std::stoi(argv[i]);
(gdb) c
Continuing.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stoi

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
50  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
```

So, I guess the error lies somewhere between lines 19 and 21, but I really can't figure out what the error is. Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: If the program has a logic bug which gets triggered during a specially crafted input, gdb is not going to help. It's purpose is to analyze the state of the application and not fuzzing to find bugs. So, you need to figure out what the application is trying to do, what algorithms it's using, what corner cases could it lead to and you will find your bug. From your gdb output, it seems that you need to run your app with some input.

Also, std::stoi can only work for int values. For anything longer, it will end up throwing an exception. Depending on what are you debugging, your ans may change.

Comment: Glad to see that you're being taught to use a debugger, that's not common. You didn't seem to be sure of how to use one however. Maybe you need a demonstration instead of a theoretical description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
>  what():  stoi
> ```

The function that `throw`s an exception is [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) that is used to interpret a signed integer value in a string.

In this loop:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
    // atoi converts a string to a number
    int number = std::stoi(argv[i]);
```

you're trying to convert `argv[0]` (the program name) into an integer. If your program name isn't a number, you're out of luck.

Start the loop at `1` to only try to convert the program  *arguments* to integers.

Comment: Thank you! But now i get this ```Breakpoint 2, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdf08) at debug-1.cc:19
19   for (std::size_t i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Reversing order of numbers

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::construct<int, int const&> (
    this=0x7fffffffddb0, __p=0x55555556ceb0)
    at /usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:147
147  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
(gdb) c
Continuing.
```

Comment: @livinglikelarry This question could have just as many answers as there are bugs. When the reason for the `invalid_argument` exception which I mention in my answer has been fixed another error like the one Adrian mentions will likely pop up. Please concentrate your question to one problem at a time. My answer fixes the problem shown in your question. if you can't solve the second problem, it's probably solved by Adrians answer.

Comment: Ok thank you! You solved my question and in combination with adrians answer the code works

Comment: oh you are right. This was my first question and im new here. I thought it would be possible to select both answers as right. My bad

Comment: @livinglikelarry I see. No problem. it's just something to think about in the future.:)

Answer (score 1):

In your `reversed` function, there is a serious problem in the following line:

```cpp
    for (std::size_t i = v.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) result.push_back(v[i]);
```

The problem is that the [`std__size_t` type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) is ***unsigned***. So, how can the test condition, `i >= 0` ever be false? When `i` gets to `0`, the `--i` operation will 'roll over' (*roll under?*) to the highest possible value for an integer of that type.

So, that `for` loop will never end (unless the attempt to access `v[i]` when `i` equals `SIZE_MAX` causes the program to crash).

A good compiler, with all warnings enabled, should tell you about this. Clang-cl (in Visual Studio 2019) gives:

> warning : result of comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always
> true [-Wtautological-unsigned-zero-compare]

And Visual Studio's native MSVC compiler gives:

> warning C4296: '>=': expression is always true

Comment: Ahh nice, thank you. I changed the std::size_t to an int and the program works now!

Comment: This is a result of using size_t for STL container sizes. It looks completely reasonable, but it violates the recommendation that you should avoid arithmetic operations and comparisons with unsigned values, because the logic is not really intuitive.

Comment: @U.W. Yep. I find the *unsigned* `size_t` a real pain. I believe Bjarne Stroustrup has also expressed his opinion that unsigned integers should be reserved for bit-manipulation stuffs, and that the STL implementers made a mistake. But we have to live with it.